# Problem with drawing 16-sided shape in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

Is there any formula or function to draw a 16-sided shape directly?
I write a code for 16-sided shape but it doesn't satisfy me.
And I want to put the page number inside a 16-sided shape.
How can I do it?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\clip(-10.13291673529722,-9.435386632879322) rectangle (9.695190117199873,4.648701636574812);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-3,-3)-- (-3,-4);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-3,-4)-- (-2,-5);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-2,-5)-- (-3,-6);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-3,-6)-- (-3,-7);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-3,-7)-- (-4,-7);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-4,-7)-- (-5,-8);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-5,-8)-- (-6,-7);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-6,-7)-- (-7,-7);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-7,-7)-- (-7,-6);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-7,-6)-- (-8,-5);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-8,-5)-- (-7,-4);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-7,-4)-- (-7,-3);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-7,-3)-- (-6,-3);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-6,-3)-- (-5,-2);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-5,-2)-- (-4,-3);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-4,-3)-- (-3,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And I what a function as the same as drawing a diamond!

```
\tikzset{%
  pics/diamond/.style args={name=#1}{%
    code={%
      \begin{scope}[local bounding box=#1,scale=0.25]
        \draw (0,0)--++(0:1)--++(-45:1.2)--++(45:1.2)--++(0:1)--++(90:1)--++(45:1.2)--++(135:1.2)--++(90:1)--++(180:1)--++(135:1.2)--++(225:1.2)--++(180:1)--++(-90:1)--++(-135:1.2)--++(-45:1.2)--cycle;
      \end{scope}
    }
  }
}
%سربرگ ها 
\fancypagestyle{mainstyle}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\myfancynum}

\fancyhead[LE]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=west] at ([xshift=12ex,yshift=-14ex]current page.north west) {\textcolor{cyan}{\rl{ test}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[RO]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
%    \node[anchor=east] at ([xshift=-12ex,yshift=-14ex]current page.north east){\textcolor{cyan}{\large\rl{\leftmark}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
%\textcolor{cyan}{\leftmark}
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\linespread{1}
\newcommand{\myfancynum}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,yshift=2cm]
%      \path (0,0) [use as bounding box]
%        node[diamond, draw=cyan, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=32pt] (pageno) {\thepage} ;
\pic at (0,0) {diamond={name=a}};
\node at (a.center){\thepage};
\pic at (0,0) {diamond={name=a}};
\node at (a.center){\thepage};
    \checkoddpage\ifoddpage
    % 36pt = 32pt + 4pt +4pt; 
    \path (pageno.west) node[fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.4, diamond, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=16pt] {};
   \draw[cyan] (pageno.north) ++(0, +4pt) -- ++(55pt, -55pt) -- ++(2\linewidth,0);

    \draw[cyan] (pageno.east) ++(4pt, 0) -- ++(-60pt, -60pt) -- ++(0, -4cm);


    \else
    \path (pageno.east) node[fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.4, diamond, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=16pt] {};
    \draw[cyan] (pageno.north) ++(0, +4pt) -- ++(-55pt, -55pt) -- ++(-2\linewidth,0);%-40,-40
    \draw[cyan] (pageno.west) ++(-4pt,0) -- ++(60pt, -60pt) -- ++(0, -4cm);

    \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyfoot[OL]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\foreach \x in {1,...,250}
\draw[color=cyan,xshift=2cm,yshift=-0.5cm] node  {\color{cyan}\rule{\paperwidth}{.1pt}};
\node[fill=cyan, fill opacity=1, diamond, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=16pt,xshift=12.4cm,yshift=-0.5cm] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\fancyfoot[ER]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\foreach \x in {1,...,250}
%\draw[color=cyan,xshift=-2cm,yshift=-1.5cm] node  {\color{cyan}\rule{\paperwidth}{.1pt}};
%\node[fill=cyan, fill opacity=1, diamond, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=16pt,xshift=-12.4cm,yshift=-1.5cm] {};%cric fot
%
\draw[color=cyan,xshift=-2cm,yshift=-0.5cm] node  {\color{cyan}\rule{\paperwidth}{.1pt}};
\node[fill=cyan, fill opacity=1, diamond, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=16pt,xshift=-12.4cm,yshift=-0.5cm] {};%cric fot
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\fancypagestyle{tocstyle}{%
%\fancyhf{} 
%\fancyhead[C]{%
%\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
%j
%\end{tikzpicture}
%}
% }
```

[image]

it is a 16 sides shape.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These shapes are known as stars. You can play with the `star point ratio`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[draw,star,star points=8]{hello}; 
 \node[draw,star,star points=8,star point ratio=1.25] at (3,0) {hello};
 \node[draw,star,star points=8,star point ratio=0.8] at (6,0) {hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if filled  as blue? what we should do?

Comment: @SajjadEsmaili Just add `fill=blue`, e.g.`\node[draw,star,star points=8,star point ratio=1.25,fill=blue] at (3,0) {hello};`

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  pics/diamond/.style args={name=#1}{
    code={
      \begin{scope}[local bounding box=#1,scale=0.5]
        \draw (0,0)--++(0:1)--++(-45:1.2)--++(45:1.2)--++(0:1)--++(90:1)--++(45:1.2)--++(135:1.2)--++(90:1)--++(180:1)--++(135:1.2)--++(225:1.2)--++(180:1)--++(-90:1)--++(-135:1.2)--++(-45:1.2)--cycle;
      \end{scope}
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic at (0,0) {diamond={name=a}};
\node at (a.center){\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i wait to draw shape that is  in the picture
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCMoQ.png

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\setcounter{page}{111}
\newcommand\PAGE%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  box/.style args = {##1/##2}{draw, minimum size=\dimexpr9mm-##1\pgflinewidth, 
                            rotate=##2, fill=white},
                    ]
\node [box=0/0] {};
\node [box=0/45] {};
\node [box=1/0, draw=none] {\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\PAGE
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoted. But one question: I wrote (for myself) a solution to this problem in MetaPost+ConTeXt. In MetaPost there is an `unfill` command that is handy in situations like this. I could not find a similar command in tikz. Do you know if it exists? It would be nice in case the background is not white.

Comment: @mickep, I'm not very familiar to MetaPost ... so I guess that `fill=none` is some how close to `unfill` command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i wait to draw shape that is in the picture i.stack.imgur.com/JCMoQ.png

Comment: @SajjadEsmaili, one problem per question please! For first version of question you receive two answer, which both solve your problem. Select one of them and than ask new question with your new problem.

Comment: @Zarko It's the first time I see `\usetikzlibrary{turtle}`, but your MWE works even without it!