# Color the area below the function tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
\draw[->] (-0.1,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.1) -- (0,6) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[scale=1,domain=0:5,smooth,variable=\x,black] plot ({\x},{\x});
\draw[black,-] (1,0,0) -- (1,1,0) node[midway,right] {};
\draw[black,-] (4,0,0) -- (4,4,0) node[midway,right] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I need to color the area below the function, representing an integral.
If possible colorize in gradient

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
\draw[->] (-0.1,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.1) -- (0,6) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[left color=blue,right color=blue!30] (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (4,4) |-cycle; 
\draw[scale=1,domain=0:5,smooth,variable=\x,black] plot ({\x},{\x});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: is parameter `scale=1` really needed in drawing a plot? I don't think so.

Comment: @Zarko No it is not, nor smooth for a straight line, nor `domain` in the options of the `tikzpicture` when the domain gets overwritten later. Yet none of this is as superfluous as `\usetikzlibrary{turtle}` in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/497484/121799 ;-)